# How to remove the value from formData before submitting in java script

Tags: javascript

Here I am preparing formData values and stored to one hidden variable.So I want to remove the value Once added to **res** variable.Any idea?

I tried formData.delete(pair[0]);...Didn't work

```
function prepareOCPDepEntries(isButton){

    var formEl = document.forms.mainForm;
    var formData = new FormData(formEl);
    var res = "";
     for(var pair of formData.entries()) {
       if(pair[0].startsWith("_")){
        res = res +"|"+ pair;
        formData.delete(pair[0]);
       }
    }
    document.getElementById("depEntry").value = res;
    document.forms.mainForm.disabled = true;
}
```

HTML code ;

pair[0] will be _0.0

```
<select name="_0.0" id="_0.0" >
<option value="1" >Y</option>
<option value="0" selected>N</option>
<option value="2" >A</option>
<option value="3" >T1</option>
<option value="4" >T2</option>
<option value="5" >T3</option>
</select></TD>
<select name="_0.1" id="_0.2" >
<option value="1" >Y</option>
<option value="0" selected>N</option>
<option value="2" >A</option>
<option value="3" >T1</option>
<option value="4" >T2</option>
<option value="5" >T3</option>
</select></TD>
```

Comment: I tried that solution like formData.delete(pair[0]);

Comment: do you know if the if condition works?

Comment: Yeah if condition works fine..No issues with that

Comment: If you do `console.log(pair[0])` ... what do you see in console? A `String`?

Comment: Yes I am getting  _0.0

pair[0] = _0.0 (this is the key value)

Comment: Than the above should work....

Comment: Yeah I tried Still in form data the deleted values are there

Comment: @SriramKumar where and how are you testing that the values are still there? Can you possibly create a [mcve]?

Comment: can you show how is your html form? Just edit your post

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan After adding  this formData.delete(pair[0]); then clicking apply button .

That time I can see the value in network tab (request body)

Comment: @SriramKumar please, create a [mcve]. Should not be that hard to drop some HTML in a snippet above. [edit].

Comment: Also, why you first do `res = res +"|"+ pair;` and than you delete it?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan   I have a lot of form data entries So I am preparing with pipe separated value and assigned to the hidden variable. In Server-side using the hidden variable, I am getting all values and processing.

That works fine. But I want to delete that entires which are the values  I prepared with pipe separated. Even I am not using that as using a hidden variable.

So there is no use of entires that's why I am trying to delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function prepareOCPDepEntries(formEl) {
  const formData = new FormData(formEl);
  let res = "";
  for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
    console.log(pair[0])
    if (pair[0].startsWith("_")) {
      console.log(pair[0])
      res = res + "|" + pair;
      formData.delete(pair[0]);
    }
  }
  console.log([...formData.entries()]); // Works. There's only one entry in the Iterator
  document.getElementById("depEntry").value = res;
  document.forms.mainForm.disabled = true;
}

document.querySelector("#mainForm").addEventListener("submit", function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  prepareOCPDepEntries(this);
})
```

```html
<form id="mainForm">
  <input value="123" name="_0.0" type="text">
  <input value="999" name="bar" type="text">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>

<textarea id="depEntry"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this snippet.I tried with this way

I have one doubt..you have added ev.preventDefault(); to avoid submit action. So when printing the form.entries the removed one(_0.0) is not there.

But If remove that line that removed value(_0.0) is again coming

Comment: If I remove ev.preventDefault() then value is again coming in formData